# バイトニックソートとマージソートの違いを教えて

Tags: アルゴリズム

動画を見たり画像見たけど違いわからなかったよ
同じ間隔離れたものを入れ替えるって共通する点じゃないか
ほら、全く違いが見えない

Answer (score 2):

マージソートは他のソートアルゴリズム(バイトニックソートを含む)と比べて、メモリには全体を格納できないほど数の多いデータを、ディスクのようなシーケンシャルアクセスが主体の外部記憶装置に格納しつつソートするのに有用です。